# Can't set uuid primary field in postgresql table flask-sqlalchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am creating a backend with multiple tables have user id as the primary field with is of UUID type in the postgresql database. But I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ayushs/.local/share/virtualenvs/Server-D_x4HQZH/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1179, in _execute_context
    context = constructor(dialect, self, conn, *args)
  File "/home/ayushs/.local/share/virtualenvs/Server-D_x4HQZH/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 743, in _init_compiled
    for key in compiled_params
  File "/home/ayushs/.local/share/virtualenvs/Server-D_x4HQZH/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 743, in <genexpr>
    for key in compiled_params
  File "/home/ayushs/.local/share/virtualenvs/Server-D_x4HQZH/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/psycopg2.py", line 487, in process
    value = _python_UUID(value)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/uuid.py", line 157, in __init__
    hex = hex.replace('urn:', '').replace('uuid:', '')
AttributeError: 'UUID' object has no attribute 'replace'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ayushs/.local/share/virtualenvs/Server-D_x4HQZH/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1832, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/ayushs/.local/share/virtualenvs/Server-D_x4HQZH/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1818, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/ayushs/.local/share/virtualenvs/Server-D_x4HQZH/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 458, in wrapper
    resp = resource(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ayushs/.local/share/virtualenvs/Server-D_x4HQZH/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/views.py", line 88, in view
    return self.dispatch_request(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ayushs/.local/share/virtualenvs/Server-D_x4HQZH/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 573, in dispatch_request
    resp = meth(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/mnt/home/Programming/Projects/Social Network/Server/src/new_user.py", line 17, in post
    self.database_helper(args)
  File "/mnt/home/Programming/Projects/Social Network/Server/src/new_user.py", line 26, in database_helper
    db.session.commit()
  File "/home/ayushs/.local/share/virtualenvs/Server-D_x4HQZH/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/scoping.py", line 162, in do
    return getattr(self.registry(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ayushs/.local/share/virtualenvs/Server-D_x4HQZH/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1026, in commit
    self.transaction.commit()
  File "/home/ayushs/.local/share/virtualenvs/Server-D_x4HQZH/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 493, in commit
    self._prepare_impl()
  File "/home/ayushs/.local/share/virtualenvs/Server-D_x4HQZH/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 472, in _prepare_impl
    self.session.flush()
  File "/home/ayushs/.local/share/virtualenvs/Server-D_x4HQZH/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2458, in flush
    self._flush(objects)
  File "/home/ayushs/.local/share/virtualenvs/Server-D_x4HQZH/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2596, in _flush
    transaction.rollback(_capture_exception=True)
  File "/home/ayushs/.local/share/virtualenvs/Server-D_x4HQZH/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 68, in __exit__
    compat.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb)
  File "/home/ayushs/.local/share/virtualenvs/Server-D_x4HQZH/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 129, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/ayushs/.local/share/virtualenvs/Server-D_x4HQZH/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2556, in _flush
    flush_context.execute()
  File "/home/ayushs/.local/share/virtualenvs/Server-D_x4HQZH/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 422, in execute
    rec.execute(self)
  File "/home/ayushs/.local/share/virtualenvs/Server-D_x4HQZH/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 589, in execute
    uow,
  File "/home/ayushs/.local/share/virtualenvs/Server-D_x4HQZH/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 245, in save_obj
    insert,
  File "/home/ayushs/.local/share/virtualenvs/Server-D_x4HQZH/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 1066, in _emit_insert_statements
    c = cached_connections[connection].execute(statement, multiparams)
  File "/home/ayushs/.local/share/virtualenvs/Server-D_x4HQZH/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 988, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/home/ayushs/.local/share/virtualenvs/Server-D_x4HQZH/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 287, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/home/ayushs/.local/share/virtualenvs/Server-D_x4HQZH/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1107, in _execute_clauseelement
    distilled_params,
  File "/home/ayushs/.local/share/virtualenvs/Server-D_x4HQZH/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1182, in _execute_context
    e, util.text_type(statement), parameters, None, None
  File "/home/ayushs/.local/share/virtualenvs/Server-D_x4HQZH/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1466, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    util.raise_from_cause(sqlalchemy_exception, exc_info)
  File "/home/ayushs/.local/share/virtualenvs/Server-D_x4HQZH/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 383, in raise_from_cause
    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cause)
  File "/home/ayushs/.local/share/virtualenvs/Server-D_x4HQZH/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 128, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/home/ayushs/.local/share/virtualenvs/Server-D_x4HQZH/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1179, in _execute_context
    context = constructor(dialect, self, conn, *args)
  File "/home/ayushs/.local/share/virtualenvs/Server-D_x4HQZH/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 743, in _init_compiled
    for key in compiled_params
  File "/home/ayushs/.local/share/virtualenvs/Server-D_x4HQZH/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 743, in <genexpr>
    for key in compiled_params
  File "/home/ayushs/.local/share/virtualenvs/Server-D_x4HQZH/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/psycopg2.py", line 487, in process
    value = _python_UUID(value)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/uuid.py", line 157, in __init__
    hex = hex.replace('urn:', '').replace('uuid:', '')
sqlalchemy.exc.StatementError: (builtins.AttributeError) 'UUID' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

Here is my model:

```
from database.shared_db import db
from sqlalchemy.dialects import postgresql
from database.shared_bycrypt import bcrypt

class AuthenticationModel(db.Model):
    user_id = db.Column('UserId', postgresql.UUID, primary_key = True)
    email = db.Column('Email', postgresql.TEXT, unique = False, nullable=False)
    phone_no = db.Column('PhoneNo', postgresql.TEXT, unique = False, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column('Password', postgresql.TEXT, unique = False, nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % self.user_id

    @property
    def password_raw(self):
        raise AttributeError('password not readable')
    @password_raw.setter
    def password_raw(self, password):
        self.password = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(password)

    def verify_password(self, password):
        return bcrypt.check_password_hash(self.password, password)
```

And here is what my database helper function:

```
def database_helper(self, args):
        id = uuid4()
        userAuth = AuthenticationModel(user_id=id, email=args['email'], phone_no=args['phone_no'], password_raw=args['password'])
        userInfo = PersonalInfoModel(user_id=id, first_name=args['first_name'], last_name=args['last_name'], dob=args['dob'])
        db.session.add(userAuth)
        db.session.add(userInfo)
        db.session.commit()
```

I found many examples of autogenerating UUID fields.  However, if I want to create some user across multiple databases, how can I do that? Because I think I will need to be able to pass the user id to the other tables even if I autogenerate it for one of the tables. Or should I simply use a text field?

Answer (score 3):

`uuid4()` is generating a UUID instance.

You want to pass a string for the `user_id` field. Convert it to a string

```py
user_id = str(uuid4())
```

If you like to pass UUID instance around and get them back in the result, you should update the user_id field in your schema to:

```py
user_id = db.Column('UserId', postgresql.UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True)
```

Comment: `id = db.Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)`

I do not recommend stringing the UUID, especially if you plan on utilizing  that column to establish a foreign key relationship with another table...

Comment: @EricMilliot-Martinez Thats beside the point. Strings can be used for foreign key relationship with another table. What are you speaking to?

Comment: In your answer @Oluwafemi Sule, `user_id = str(uuid4())` is specifically the point that I was speaking to.  I strongly recommend people don't do that.  Why?  Because I just got done resolving a bug where this was the issue, because let's say `user_id` is also being used as a foreign key in a different table.  I was having problems committing more than one instance(record) of that new table and would have to restart the app in order to save another object to the db. I stop stringing the uuid as showed with `default=uuid.uuid4` and the save issue is resolved.

Comment: From this page: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/postgresql.html :
`as_uuid=False¶ – if True, values will be interpreted as Python uuid objects, converting to/from string via the DBAPI.`

Comment: If you're going to use a string for UUID, then your default factory should be returning a string and not a UUID object to avoid type mismatches. In this posted question, the OP has declared the field without a default factory and with a type of `postgresql.UUID`. They must pass a string value in that case for the field. If they declared the field with the `as_uuid=True`, passing a UUID object is fine. [Here are some tests](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/8e9e473dcb76b57a7f0eaa476481cb66a258ea69/test/dialect/postgresql/test_types.py#L2216) that clarify this behavior.

Comment: OP didn't have the flag `as_uuid` in his code, but you did in your answer to him and it's important to understand what this flag does because it can cause problems, especially when dealing with foreign key relationships.  The test code you just shared highlights the importance with that flag.  I've also had bugs I've had to resolve because of the inappropriate usage of this `as_uuid` flag.